# Can't use tab completion when using awk in command line

Tags: bash, awk, autocomplete

I am trying to separate a tab-delimited file using awk.

```
awk -F'\t' -v OFS="\t" '{if ($5=="Pattern") print $0}' My_file
```

I came into problem that I can't not use tab completion with the option " **-v OFS="\t"** ". Whenever the command contain " **-v OFS="\t"** "(whether it is the only option or in combination with other option), I can not use tab completion for filename.

When I use:

```
awk -F'\t' '{if ($5=="Pattern") print $0}' My_file
```

The tab completion works fine.

And sometimes when I use the following command:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '{if ($5=="Pattern") print $0}' My_file
```

There will be error:

> bash: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
>
> bash: syntax error: unexpected end of file

When I paste the filename, but not by tab completion, the command actually works.

Can anyone tell me what I am been doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: By "auto type-in" I assume you mean tab completion?

Comment: Try:  awk -v 'OFS="\t"; {if ($5=="Pattern") print $0}'

Comment: Hi Jason, thanks for the correction. Yes, by auto type-in I mean use tab completion to complete the filename in command line.

Comment: When trying `awk -v 'OFS="\t"; {if ($5=="Pattern") print $0}' `, the tab completion works fine.          But it raise another error "awk: 1: unexpected character '.'", if the file name contain **"."**.            I rename the filename with no ".", but now the command takes a long time to run(which it shouldn't be) and I kill it with ctrl+c.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead :

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t"; OFS="\t"}{if ($5=="Pattern") print $0}' My_file
```

If I understood your problem, that should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you so much! That actually works and the result is correct. Is it necessary to include the file delimiter option in the apostrophes?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what happened when you passed the FS value through the `-v` option, but using the `-v` option should be used primarly when you want to pass a value that is contained in a shell variable, like :
`$ awk -v x=$someValue ...`
if your value is a constant, you can initialize it in a  `BEGIN` block. Anything in such a block in awk will be executed _before_ going through the file. Similarly, there is an `END` block that is executed once all the file has been read. You can set field separator (FS) and output field separator (OFS) in any block.

Comment: To answer your question you don't _need_ to set FS and OFS inside the awk instructions, but apparently the presence of `\t` in your command line seemed to confuse your inline shell editor. You could also try `$ myFS='\t'; awk -F"$myFS" -v OFS="$myFS" ...`, it might work.